# Python VLookup-esque function

Tags: python, dataframe, probability

I am trying to assign probabilities to a series of data:

```
data = df['main']
n = len(data)
frequencytable = pd.cut(df['main'], bins=10)
```

I can calculate probability of the event with:

```
frequencytable.value_counts()/n
```

How can I then assign the respective value to the original dataset? Ideally a new column in the original data frame representing the bucket in which the 'main' value falls into.

Sample data:

```
`Date/Time,Max Temp (°C)  
2021-01-01,9  
2021-01-02,8.5  
2021-01-03,9  
2021-01-04,9  
2021-01-05,9.5  
2021-01-06,9.5  
2021-01-07,14  
2021-01-08,9  
2021-01-09,10.5  
2021-01-10,11 
2021-01-11,10.5  
2021-01-12,7  
2021-01-13,6.5  
2021-01-14,14  
2021-01-15,9  
2021-01-16,9  
2021-01-17,9  
2021-01-18,9  
2021-01-19,9.5  
2021-01-20,4  
2021-01-21,5  
2021-01-22,4.5  
2021-01-23,3.5  
2021-01-24,4.5  
2021-01-25,4  
2021-01-26,4.5  
2021-01-27,4  
2021-01-28,4.5  
2021-01-29,7.5  
2021-01-30,8  
2021-01-31,7.5
```

Comment: Can you paste some sample data in a CSV format, please?

Comment: Welcome if you want the precentage of the occurence of the values in the `main` column you can use this: `df['main'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100`

Comment: I think I correctly added sample data!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Get value counts as a percentage - @Eitan Rosati
counts = df['main'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

# Convert value counts to dictionary
counts_dict = {x[0]: x[1] for x in counts.itertuples(index=False)}

# Assign new column with probability
probability = df['main'].apply(lambda x: counts_dict[x]) # Get count value
df['probability'] = probability
```

Note that this code is stitched together (may be a few minor faults - please let me know). Credits below:

[how to convert value_counts() of pd.cut to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348216/how-to-convert-value-counts-of-pd-cut-to-a-dictionary/53348446)

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html